# T-SQL replication - Skip a specific command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If i know the xact_seqno of the specific replication command how can i skip replicating that command?
Can i somehow clear it in the Logs somehow?

MS SQL Server 2008 R2

AHIA, 
denaem

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think you'd want to.  Replication is particularly finicky with respect to state.  If you skip a command, that state is disrupted and you potentially cause problems downstream.  For instance, let's say that you skip in insert command.  Later, a delete command will fail because it fails to find that row.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can skip it but you can delete it from MSrepl_commands on the distributor.

You can use `sp_browsereplc`

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MSrepl_commands
WHERE xact_seqno = ''
```